# How should my educational letters follow my name?

Tags: cv

I have a AA, BA, MAML (Associates, Bachelors and Masters of Arts in Management and Leadership).

I just recently completed my Certification in Management and Leadership, General Business as well as my Certification in Advanced Graduate Studies.  How do I capture all of these in my signature line?

Currently I sign off as:
Jane Doe, MA (although it should be MAML)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm somewhat surprised: of all fields, I'd have expected that business students are the ones who know most about things important for business communication.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on your local country/culture. It also depends on the context of use and how formal you want to be. Your current usage is probably best for most usages, however. I'm assuming the US and similar locations. Germany tends to be more formal in such things.

If you need to be specific (in context) about your field, use MAML, though it might not be well known. I've seldom seen associates degrees listed, but Jane Doe, BA, MA would be common enough in a formal situation.

Usually a higher degree will imply some lower level degree so it normally isn't necessary to list everything unless you need the formality. I hold BA, MA, and PhD, but very seldom list all three, using only the last.

Comment: As you mention Germany: yes, we tend to be more formal - but long rows of letters as I've seen them in the email signature of UK colleagues are untypical over here. Once you have a master's, the bachelor isn't mentioned any more.  Inside academia, even the PhD is rarely put to the name. It's more common to write the current job position, plus maybe profession if it's not implied by the position. For businesses it's more formal as email signatures have legal requirements (like letters), e.g. business emails must contain stuff like who's CEO and trade registry no etc.

Comment: What about adding on the certifications?  How would one do that?

Comment: I would suggest not listing any of them unless in application for a job that requires one of them. Even then, there are probably better ways to communicate that you hold the required certificate(s). Perhaps in a letter of application.